# java.lang.NullPointerExeption before onCreate called for android app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm having a tremendous amount of trouble figuring out how and why I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException. I have no idea what is going on because it seems to happen before my program loads. I've set a breakpoint at the first line of my onCreate function and my android log still shows that I have a this exception thrown but the program continues to start and I reach my breakpoint. But stepping through I get very weird behavior. I will post the code in question as well as the log. if any other info needed to help me with this please ask. Also please excuse the indention. I'm fairly new to stack overflow

```
package com.example.facta.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by facta on 11/21/2014.
 */
public class SiteConfig {
    private XmlResourceParser configParser;
    ArrayList<RSSProviderInfo> RSSProviderInfos;
    ArrayList<String> RSSProviderNames;

public SiteConfig()
{
    RSSProviderInfos = new ArrayList<RSSProviderInfo>();
    RSSProviderNames = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public ArrayList<RSSProviderInfo> getProvierInfos()
{
    return RSSProviderInfos;
}
public ArrayList<String> getProvierNames()
{
    return RSSProviderNames;
}

public void loadConfig(Context context, int resourceId)
{
    configParser = context.getResources().getXml(resourceId);
    RSSProviderInfos.clear();

    RSSProviderInfo providerInfo = new RSSProviderInfo();

    ArrayList<String> providerNames = loadProviders(configParser);

    for(int i=0; i < providerNames.size(); i++)
    {
        providerInfo = LoadProviderInfo(configParser, providerNames.get(i));
        if(providerInfo != null && providerInfo.isComplete()) {
            RSSProviderInfos.add(providerInfo);
        }
    }
}

private RSSProviderInfo LoadProviderInfo(XmlResourceParser parser, String provider) {

    RSSProviderInfo info = new RSSProviderInfo();
    String attrName = new String();

    try {
        parser.next();
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG
                    && parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("site" )) {

                attrName = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");

                if(attrName.equalsIgnoreCase(provider + ".enabled"))
                {
                  /*
                    String value = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                    if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                        Log.d("LoadProviderInfo", "value does equal no");
                        return null; //If it's not enabled don't include it in the config
                    }
                    */
                }
                else if(attrName.equalsIgnoreCase(provider + ".elementTag"))
                {
                    info.setElementTag(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value"));
                }
                else if(attrName.equalsIgnoreCase(provider + ".titleTag"))
                {
                    info.setTitleTag(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value"));
                }
                else if(attrName.equalsIgnoreCase(provider + ".linkTag"))
                {
                    info.setLinkTag(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value"));
                }
                else if(attrName.equalsIgnoreCase(provider + ".descriptionTag"))
                {
                    info.setDescriptionTag(parser.getAttributeValue(null,"value"));
                }
                else if(attrName.equalsIgnoreCase(provider + ".url"))
                {
                    info.addUrl(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value"));
                }
                break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("loadProviderInfo", "Caught an exeption: " + e.toString() + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement st[] = e.getStackTrace();
        for(int i=0; i < st.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("loadProviderInfo", "StackTraceElement[" + i + "] " + st[i].getLineNumber());

        }
    }



    return null;
}

private ArrayList<String> loadProviders(XmlResourceParser parser) {

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        parser.next();
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG
                    && parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("siteproviders")) {

               String[] parsedNames = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value").split(",");

                for (int i=0; i < parsedNames.length; i++)
                {
                    names.add(i, parsedNames[i]);
                }
                break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("loadProviderInfo", "Caught an exeption: " + e.toString() + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement st[] = e.getStackTrace();
        for(int i=0; i < st.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("loadProviderInfo", "StackTraceElement[" + i + "] " + st[i].getLineNumber());

        }

    }

    return names;
}


}
```

---

Log Below

```
11-23 18:20:40.830      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-23 18:20:41.569      537-542/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-23 18:20:41.580      537-542/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication D/loadProviders﹕ Caught an exeption: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.facta.myapplication.SiteConfig.loadProviders(SiteConfig.java:119)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.facta.myapplication.SiteConfig.loadConfig(SiteConfig.java:42)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.facta.myapplication.ResultsActivity.fetch(ResultsActivity.java:94)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.example.facta.myapplication.ResultsActivity.onCreate(ResultsActivity.java:62)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-23 18:20:42.040      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 18:20:42.070      537-542/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-23 18:20:42.080      537-542/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-23 18:20:42.270      537-537/com.example.facta.myapplication D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-23 18:37:36.440      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.example.facta.myapplication is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-23 18:37:36.490      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
11-23 18:37:36.701      669-675/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
11-23 18:37:36.740      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
11-23 18:37:36.740      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-23 18:37:36.900      669-674/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-23 18:37:36.910      669-674/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-23 18:37:36.940      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-23 18:37:37.140      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-23 18:37:37.680      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-23 18:37:37.880      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-23 18:37:38.079      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-23 18:37:38.279      669-669/com.example.facta.myapplication I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
11-23 18:37:38.369      669-674/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-23 18:37:38.379      669-674/com.example.facta.myapplication I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

---

Calling Activity Below

```
package com.example.facta.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/* TODO
   Need to make a config file that has the following format.
   site.names          = CNN,FOX,NBC,AP

   site.CNN.enabled   = yes
   site.CNN.searchtag = item
   site.CNN.titletag  = title
   site.CNN.linktag   = link
   site.CNN.descriptiontag = description
   site.CNN.numurls   = 10
   site.CNN.url.1     = "https://www.cnn.com/top_stories.rss
   site.CNN.url.2     = "https://www.cnn.com/world_politics.rss

   site.FOX.enabled   = no
   site.FOX.searchtag = story

 */



public class ResultsActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> finalUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_us.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_latest.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_allpolitics.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_crime.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_tech.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_health.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_showbiz.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_travel.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_living.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_freevideo.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_studentnews.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_mostpopular.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_latest.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.ireport.com/feeds/oncnn.rss");
    finalUrls.add("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_behindthescenes.rss");
    this.fetch();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_results, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void fetch() {
    /**TODO possibly load config then for each provider pass in RSSProviderInfo into HandleXML
     That way HandleXML can set all the tags it needs and then parse the urls from the param
     */

    SiteConfig siteConfig = new SiteConfig();
    siteConfig.loadConfig(this, R.xml.sites);
    ArrayList<RSSProviderInfo> siteConfigProvierInfos = siteConfig.getProvierInfos();

    for (int k = 0; k < siteConfigProvierInfos.size(); k++) {

        HandleXML obj = new HandleXML(siteConfigProvierInfos.get(k));
        obj.fetchXML();

        while (!obj.parsingComplete) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500, 0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final ArrayList<RSSInfo> rssInfos = obj.getRssInfos();
            final TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.results_table);

            Log.d("fetch", "Size of rssinfos " + rssInfos.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < rssInfos.size(); i++) {
                final int index = i;
                final TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //Get information from infos
                final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText(rssInfos.get(index).getTitle());
                textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tableRow.setClickable(true);
                tableRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssInfos.get(index).getLink()));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                tableRow.addView(textView);
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

            }

            Log.d("fetch", "tableLayout = " + tableLayout.toString());

        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: What is at line 119 of `SiteConfig`. It looks like something there is your problem. `parser` possibly?

Comment: `        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();` Thanks for the help. That is line line 119 of SiteConfig. Not sure if this is the problem as it looks pretty simple.

Comment: Are you sure? Because that line can't produce a NPE. Did you check the `parser` variable as mentioned above?

Comment: following the calling code to calls loadConfig from an activity like so loadConfig(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.sites). I'm researching now and since I'm calling from within an activity should it be loadConfig(this, R.xml.sites) instead of calling getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Most likely since you're calling from an `Activity` but I'm not sure that is the immediate problem. Go ahead and try

Comment: @codeMagic Tried it and it didn't work either. Not sure what the problem is here but I'm glad I have help.

Comment: You still haven't answered if you have checked the value of `parser`? The line you indicated can't produce a NPE

Comment: @codeMagic parser = {android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser@830025683592.

Comment: @Nick.D The line you mentioned is not line 119 of `SiteConfig.java`. That line cannot cause an NPE. Until you can accurately identify the line that the stack trace points out, not much can be done to help. Please check your line numbers and do this.

Comment: i still dont get it, do you know what, clean and restart..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @JasonC. I think I need to review Android Studio. That is an error from a previous version of my code (notice the date of yesterday 11/23). I thought "clear all" in logcat literally cleared all and deleted. I just found out I am wrong. There are no NPEs at this time that I am aware of. Sorry for the waste of time....lesson learned for me using android studio. After noticing this I was able to find the logical error that caused the program to exit shortly after. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. I think I need to review Android Studio. That is an error from a previous version of my code (notice the date of yesterday 11-23). I thought "clear all" in logcat literally cleared all and delete it. I just found out I am wrong. There are no NPEs at this time that I am aware of. Sorry for the waste of time....lesson learned for me using android studio. After noticing this I was able to find the logical error that caused the program to exit shortly after. Thanks all for the help